# google maps -- incorrect pop-up information

Tags: google-maps

I have converted multiple shapefiles to KML using the Shp2kml2 software from Zonums Solutions. I have made a map with the KML layers (of which I have imported to google docs to get the url). My map is found at: http://userpages.flemingc.on.ca/~catam/collab2.html

I have:
6 polygon KML layers,
1 point KML layer,
1 Google Fusion Table point layer

But when I try to click on a specific point, the pop-up information is that of the polygon which rests in the same place as the specific point.

My code is:

```
    var map, layer2;
    function initialize() {
    var ontario = new google.maps.LatLng(49.2867873, -84.7493416);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: ontario
    }

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var openInfoWindow = function (KMLevent) {
        infoWindow.close();
        infoWindow.setOptions(
        {
            content: KMLevent.featureData.infoWindowHtml,
            position: KMLevent.latLng,
            pixelOffset: KMLevent.pixelOffset
        });
        infoWindow.open(map);
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var kmlOptions = {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,  // do not to display an info window when clicked
        preserveViewport: false,
        map: map
    };


    var urls = [
       'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkajc2OGZTZDZBV0k&export=download', // SCHOOLS, NDP, LIBERAL, PC1, PC2, PC3, 
       'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkQzRSdVB1TVRseU0&export=download',    'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkWFlscVM5N01lSDQ&export=download',     'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkbHNSTjhCN1dLQTg&export=download',      'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkdnRoYnN1bnpubEU&export=download',      'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkaHg1WlNKdU1VWHc&export=download'
    ];

    layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'col9',
      from: '1FzRSqRcxY37i7VtejqONHhAB-MrzFhakYSvZaIvo'
    }
  });
  layer2.setMap(map);


    urls.forEach(function(url) {
        var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url, kmlOptions);
        layer.setMap(map);
        KmlLayer.setZIndex(999);
        google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", openInfoWindow);

    });

}

//initialize();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the polygon layers are getting plotted over the points. Due to this even though you think you're clicking on the point the actual click event is generated on the polygon.

One solution would be to plot the polygons first followed by the points.

If that's not possible then you should set the z-index of the layer depending on whether it is a polygon or point.

```
kmlLayer.setZIndex(999);
```

The higher the z-index the higher the layer will be. I would suggest using a high z-index for the points while using a low z-index for the polygons. That should solve your problem.

The first option would be to move the url for points after the polygon urls. This should work without the need for z-index and will work without changing any of the code.

```
var urls = [
   'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkQzRSdVB1TVRseU0&export=download',    'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkWFlscVM5N01lSDQ&export=download',     'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkbHNSTjhCN1dLQTg&export=download',      'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkdnRoYnN1bnpubEU&export=download',      'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkaHg1WlNKdU1VWHc&export=download',
   'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkajc2OGZTZDZBV0k&export=download', // SCHOOLS, NDP, LIBERAL, PC1, PC2, PC3, 
];
```

The second option is to remove the points url from the array and add that separately. First plot the polygons as shown below.

```
var urls = [
   'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkQzRSdVB1TVRseU0&export=download',    'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkWFlscVM5N01lSDQ&export=download',     'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkbHNSTjhCN1dLQTg&export=download',      'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkdnRoYnN1bnpubEU&export=download',      'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkaHg1WlNKdU1VWHc&export=download',
];

urls.forEach(function(url) {
    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url, kmlOptions);
    layer.setZIndex(10);
    layer.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", openInfoWindow);
});
```

After this add the points layer

```
var pointsUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkajc2OGZTZDZBV0k&export=download'; // SCHOOLS, NDP, LIBERAL, PC1, PC2, PC3, 

var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url, kmlOptions);
layer.setZIndex(10);
layer.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", openInfoWindow);
```

Comment: I am having trouble knowing where to insert your code within my code. I have edited my post to show my code. To clarify, I have: 5 polygon KML layers, 1 point KML layer, 1 Google Fusion Table point layer

Comment: Hi I have updated the answer. Try changing the position of the url. Let me know in case it doesn't work.

Comment: It worked for the KML point layer (schools). However, my point layer from google fusion table does not show up in the map now.

Comment: the code `var pointsUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B79b02nBK5vkajc2OGZTZDZBV0k&export=download';` has the same link as the last link in `var urls`. Perhaps this has something to do with the problem?

Comment: Don't use the second method if changing the order of the urls works. Move the Google Fusion table  code to after  the polygon layers code and it should work.

Comment: I changed the order of the urls (put schools last) and it worked for the school points KML layer. My google fusion table points layer shows up in the map but when I click on its points, I get the InfoWindow of the polygons. I have not changed any of my code (apart from placing the schools points layer last) and the google fusion table code is placed after the `var urls = [ ...]`

Comment: Is the google fusion table code after this code ? 

urls.forEach(function(url) {
    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url, kmlOptions);
    layer.setZIndex(10);
    layer.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", openInfoWindow);
});

Comment: yes, the google fusion table code is after that particular code